# Connection two wireless ADSL routers to share IPs

Tags: wireless-networking, combine

I have two wireless ADSL routers sitting right next to each other, each with his own internet connection.

I'd like to be able to connect to a computer that is connected to router A from a computer that is connected to router B, while keeping both routers internet connection individually.

i.e. If computer A is connected to router A, it will use router A internet connection, and a second computer, call it B, will be connected to router B, and will use router B internet connection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Connect a third device to both routers, configured to route traffic in the manner you prefer (load balancing, round robin or such that computerA uses routerA and computerB uses routerB).

There are a large number of options depending on what scale of solution you're looking at (eg, is this a 2 person solution for a pair of 2 Mb/s DSL lines, or a 200 person solution for a pair of 50 Mb/s DSL lines).

---

Sounds like you're after a policy based routing or similar, though there's a non-trivial challenge in differentiating between web browsing and downloading over HTTP.  I know that [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) has multi-WAN capability and it may do what you're after.

Comment: This is a situation with 2 DSL lines (5Mb and 3Mb).

The idea is that one computer will act as a download box, and the other(s) will be able to surf without feeling it, but still share stuff over the ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Another device that can route the internal network traffic with each computer group in a separate segment, would do what you want. When traffic targeted to public addresses comes from Segment A (192.168.100.X) use ADSL router A, when it comes from Segment B 192.168.200.X. use ADSL Router B. Also configure a static route to direct traffic from Segment A to Segment B and viceversa.